# Debian Stable 6.0.2 installation error

Tags: linux, debian

Trying to install Debian Stable 6.0.2, but getting error

`Debootstrap Error - failed to determine codename`

during the step "Install Basic System". I am a novice in Linux. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using CD/DVD to install? My first guess would be bad install media.

Comment: I am using USB 4GB

Comment: So? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, problem solved

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please consider providing an answer.

Comment: The problem was in my lan cable, after i fixed it - configuring lan was automaticaly and not manualy as it was before

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was in my lan cable, after i fixed it - configuring lan
>   was automaticaly and not manualy as it was before

-- self answer by [user](https://superuser.com/users/92253/user815860)